# How angular app could know if SharedWorker is already exist?

Tags: javascript, angular, shared-worker

I have some script in `SharedWorker` that do synchronization between `indexedDb` and remote `db`. But when I open addition tab or window (one of the usecases in my app) of the application it creates another synchronization process. Of course it's superfluous.

I wanted that my application will be informed if synchronization process in `SharedWorker` already exists. In case this process already exists, a new instance of app(another tab), will not create `new SharedWorker()`. How do I get it?

Comment: you can put such a flag in localStorage?

Comment: And after all tabs will be closed, how to change this flag?